# Select elements from two lists based on elements of third list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have two lists `inputA` and `inputB` containing items of some type and a third list `select` of `Bool`s. I want to construct a list where the i-th element is the i-th element of `inputA` if the i-th element of `select` is `True`, or the i-th element of `inputB` otherwise.

This can be done like this:

```
result = [if x then a else b | (x, a, b) <- zip3 select inputA inputB]
```

For example:

```
> [if x then a else b | (x,a,b) <- zip3 [True,False,False,True] [10..] [100..]]
[10,101,102,13]
```

I wonder if there is some built-in function, say `mapIfElse`, which can be used like this to produce the same result:

```
result = mapIfElse select inputA inputB
```

Comment: Confuse your reader. `result = zipWith ((. fromEnum) . (!!)) (transpose [inputB, inputA]) select` (100% not serious)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a built-in function for this that I know of, but you could more easily implement it as

```
import Data.Bool (bool)

-- I don't like bool's argument order
if_ :: Bool -> a -> a -> a
if_ cond a b = bool b a cond

-- If you are using base < 4.7 then Data.Bool.bool
-- does not exist so you can define if_ manually as
-- if_ True  a b = a
-- if_ False a b = b

mapIfElse :: [Bool] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mapIfElse = zipWith3 if_
```

This would be a more idiomatic implementation in my opinion, since it describes the operation for one set of arguments then applies that operation to the list of arguments.  Again, I don't know of an existing function to do this, but in the future if you want to search for functions of a given type try [hoogle](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle) first.

Comment: The `bool` function seems to be what I was looking for, however it is not available on my installation for some reason.

Comment: `ghc --version` gives 7.6.3

Comment: I'm using GHC 7.8.3 with base 4.7.0.1.   Looks like it was added for base 4.7.  You can obviously define it pretty easily, it's just a functional form of an `if-then-else` statement.  `bool onFalse onTrue True = onTrue; bool onFalse onTrue False = onFalse`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 That'd be the problem, you'll be using base < 4.7, but you need base >= 4.7.  If you install the latest haskell platform it should have 7.8 and base 4.7.

Comment: I share your optinion on the order of `bool`'s arguments. I guess the order was chosen to mimick other catamorphism-producers like `foldr` and `maybe`. I wish we also had in the standard libs the flipped versions of such catas, or a classy "convert to Church encoding" function.

Comment: @chi You're probably right, I think it's to be consistent with the `maybe`, `either`, etc functions where the failure action is given as the first argument, but it's still awkward to use in this case.